# Comparación de decimales en javascript erronea

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
while (i<=9){
        var concat1 = "eCorreccion"+(i-1);
        var concat2 = "eCorreccion"+i;
        var valor1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById(concat1).value).toFixed(4);
        if(valor1<0){
            valor1 = valor1 * (-1);
        }
        var valor2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById(concat2).value).toFixed(4);
        if (valor2<0){
            valor2 = valor2 * (-1);
        }

        if(i == 2){    
            if(valor1 > valor2 || isNaN(valor2)){
                max = valor1;
                alert("VALOR1 "+valor1+" "+valor2);
            }else{
                max = valor2;
                alert("VALOR2 "+valor1+" "+valor2);
            }
        }
        
        if(i != 2 && valor2 > max && !isNaN(valor2)){
            max = valor2;
        }
        
        i++;
}
```

El caso es que recorre los datos de una tabla, si estos están en negativo, los pasa a positivo, y lo único que quiero es almacenar el más alto para luego usarlo más adelante.

Como veis he puesto un alert para comprobar los datos que salen, vamos a hacer la prueba, introduzco un número:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al solo haber ese número en la tabla, lo pone como máximo ya que lo compara con nada.

El problema viene ahora, voy a introducir un número más pequeño:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si os fijáis he introducido "2.0000" y al parecer es más grande que "116.5000", no tiene ningún sentido, ¿alguna idea?

Comment: tu problema esta aquí `alert("VALOR1 "+valor1+" "+valor2);` y luego `alert("VALOR2 "+valor1+" "+valor2);` no estas alterando el orden del mensaje

Answer (score 6):

tienes que tener cuidado en javascript al realizar comparaciones. Por lo que puedo ver los valores los obtener del Dom por lo que te devuelve un string. Teniendo en cuenta que lo que te devuelve un string el resultado que te muestra es el correcto.

Lo que tienes que hacer es pasar a float esos valores para que puedas realizar la comparación que tu quieres. Ejemplo:

```
valor1 = parseFloat(valor1)
valor2 = parseFloat(valor2)
```

Después de hacer esto la comparación va a ser la que tu quieres.
Espero que te sirva

Comment: He realizado los cambios con parseFloat y aún así me sigue saliendo exactamente lo mismo. He editado la pregunta para que puedas verlo.

Comment: @Yustico mira el comentario bajo la pregunta

Comment: puedes mostrar el html y la función entera? para saber exactamente que ocurre, ya que he probado lo que te comente y si realiza bien la comparación.

Comment: Lo siento, pero acabo de ver el error. Al hacer toFixed(4) estas convirtiendo de nuevo la variable a string por lo que te vuelve a ocurrir lo mismo.

Comment: @AnonimoPer Eso es. Al necesitar los 4 decimales, había puesto el toFixed(4), pero claro, lo vuelve a string. Así que lo que he hecho ha sido realizar primero la comparación de los float y luego la variable max hacerle un toFixed(4) al final. Muchas gracias. (Pd: no se si poner la respuesta o dar ésta como la respuesta válida)

Comment: @lois6b creo que sería uno de los más indicados para saber que hacer en estos casos.

Comment: Para aceptar respuesta, si ambas son válidas busco la mejor explicada (que fue mas clara para mi) o si no puedes basarte en la hora de publicacion... @Yustico decide

Answer (score 4):

Me atrevo a decir que

```
document.getElementById(concat1).value;
```

es una `String`, no un número. De ahí que tus *intentos* de comparación numérica tengan resultados ... curiosos.

Solo tienes que *parsearlo* como números, usando `parseInt( )`:

```
while (i<=9){
    var concat1 = "eCorreccion"+(i-1);
    var concat2 = "eCorreccion"+i;
    var valor1 = parseInt( document.getElementById(concat1).value );
    if(valor1<0){
        valor1 = valor1 * (-1);
    }
    var valor2 = parseInt( document.getElementById(concat2).value );
    if (valor2<0){
        valor2 = valor2 * (-1);
    }   
    if(i == 2){ 
        if(valor1 > valor2){
            max = valor1;
            alert("VALOR1 "+valor1+" "+valor2);
        }else{
            max = valor2;
            alert("VALOR2 "+valor1+" "+valor2);
        }
    }

    if(i != 2 && valor2 > max){
        max = valor2;
    }

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Es lo que indicas pero cambiaría el parseInt por parseFloat, ya que sus datos contienen decimales.

Comment: O incluso un simple `+` delante

Comment: @PabloLozano Tengo el JavaScript oxidado, que le vamos a hacer. Teneis razón :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
while (i<=9){
            var concat1 = "eCorreccion"+(i-1);
            var concat2 = "eCorreccion"+i;
            var valor1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById(concat1).value);
            if(valor1<0){
                valor1 = valor1 * (-1);
            }
            var valor2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById(concat2).value);
            if (valor2<0){
                valor2 = valor2 * (-1);
            }

            if(i == 2){ 
                if(valor1 > valor2 || isNaN(valor2)){
                    max = valor1.toFixed(4);
                }else{
                    max = valor2.toFixed(4);
                }
            }

            if(i != 2 && valor2 > max && !isNaN(valor2)){
                max = valor2.toFixed(4);
            }

            i++;
    }
```

El problema residía en que a pesar de estár haciendo `parseFloat`, volvía a ponerse en tipo `String` al usar el `toFixed(4)`.

Se ha solucionado realizando primero la comparativa con los float y una vez realizada, parsear el valor correspondiente para así no tener fallos.